# bash wait exit on error code

Tags: bash, wait

Let's consider this as a starting point:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

echo "Sleeping..."
sleep 2 &

wait

echo "Done"
exit 0
```

I would like `wait` to exit the whole script if the background process exited with error. Introducing an error as such:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

echo "Sleeping..."
sleep SOMETHING_STRANGE_AND_WRONG &

wait

echo "Done"
exit 0
```

does echo "Done". I was expecting `wait` to exit the script, because of `set -e`.

I know that I can save the `pid` of `sleep` and check the return value of the background process this way:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

echo "Sleeping..."
sleep SOMETHING_STRANGE_AND_WRONG &
pid=$!

if wait $pid; then
    echo "Success"
else
    echo "Failure!"
    exit 1
fi

echo "Done"
exit 0
```

However, this gets cumbersome when I have several such "sync points" within my script, and several subprocesses to wait for at each of these points.

I am not very interested in the error codes themselves, only that they're not success.

Is there a less verbose way to make `wait` fail and exit (because of `set -e`) if any of the subprocesses it was waiting for did not succeed?

---

Edit: I am looking for a solution where `wait` fails and exit if *any* of the subprocesses fails:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

echo "Sleeping..."
sleep SOMETHING_STRANGE_AND_WRONG &
sleep 2 &

wait

echo "Done"
exit 0
```

which I currently solve this way (which I find cumbersome):

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

echo "Sleeping..."
pids=""
sleep SOMETHING_STRANGE_AND_WRONG &
pids+=" $!"
sleep 2 &
pids+=" $!"

for p in $pids; do
    if wait $p; then
        echo "Success"
    else
        echo "Failure"
        exit 1
    fi
done

echo "Done"
exit 0
```

Comment: The long list of exceptions to "I was expecting [foo] to exit the script, because of `set -e`" is why it is recommended you *don't* use `set -e`.

Comment: See [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) for more on that, skipping the allegory for the exercises below if in a hurry.

Answer (score 3):

Because your shebang lines are Bash I will give a Bash-specific (non-POSIX-portable) answer first (and a less elegant portable version below that).

Bash has a concise/elegant/robust way which responds to each child as they finish, not in a hardcoded loop order. The POSIX-portable version has to use a hardcoded loop, and is about as good as you can do portably. For both versions with small tweaks they can either handle-and-exit as soon as they encounter the first failure or wait until all have finished then handle-and-exit, and either way can then wait for parent-exit after all children or not (which is useful when not doing so may lead to race-conditions or zombies in your larger program).

The pertinent points regarding Bash's non-portable "wait" used in its version are:

- **optflag -f**: forces "wait" to wait for id to terminate before returning its status, instead of returning when it changes status (you may or may not want this, depending on your use-case)
- **optflag -n**: waits for a single job from the list of ids or, if no ids are supplied, any job, to complete and returns its exit status
- **exit status 127**: is returned if none of the supplied arguments is a child of the shell, or if no arguments are supplied and the shell has no unwaited-for children

Here are the key logic-snippets.

**Bash version**:

```
set -e
declare -i err=0 werr=0
while wait -fn || werr=$?; ((werr != 127)); do
  err=$werr
done
```

**POSIX portable shell version**:

```
set -e
werr=0
err=0
for pid in $pids; do
  wait $pid || werr=$?
  ! [ $werr = 127 ] || break
  err=$werr
done
```

Both versions include handling, optionally straight away or after all children have exited, and optionally waiting for parent-exit or not too (see lines for uncommenting).

**Bash version**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sleep 2 &
sleep SOMETHING_STRANGE_AND_WRONG &
sleep 1 &

set -e
declare -i err=0 werr=0
while wait -fn || werr=$?; ((werr != 127)); do
  err=$werr
  ## To handle *as soon as* first failure happens uncomment this:
  #((err == 0)) || break
done
## If you want to still wait for children to finish before exiting
## parent (even if you handle the failed child early) uncomment this:
#trap 'wait || :' EXIT
if ((err == 0)); then
  echo "Success"
else
  echo "Failure!"
  exit $err
fi
```

**POSIX portable shell version**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

pids=''
sleep 2 & pids="$pids $!"
sleep SOMETHING_STRANGE_AND_WRONG & pids="$pids $!"
sleep 1 & pids="$pids $!"

set -e
werr=0
err=0
for pid in $pids; do
  wait $pid || werr=$?
  ! [ $werr = 127 ] || break
  err=$werr
  ## To handle *as soon as* first failure happens uncomment this:
  #[ $err = 0 ] || break
done
## If you want to still wait for children to finish before exiting
## parent (even if you handle the failed child early) uncomment this:
#trap 'wait || :' EXIT
if [ $err = 0 ]; then
  echo "Success"
else
  echo "Failure!"
  exit $err
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

Shorter would be

```
wait || exit $?
```

Or if message needed, if not already logged by failing process

```
wait || { echo "background failed: $?" >&2; exit 1;}
```

or a function could be used instead

```
exit_fail() {
    echo "$1" >&2
    exit 1
}

...
wait || exit_fail "background failed: $?"
```

Comment: This does not seem to scale to several subprocesses, e.g. if I start `sleep SOMETHNG_STRANGE_AND_WRONG &` followed by `sleep 2 &`, and wait with `wait || exit $?`, the script still outputs "Done"

Comment: `wait` i mean `wait $pid`

Comment: the `|| exit 1` semantic is exactly what does `set -e` but explicitly, the assertion is that script continues if command exit status is 0. At the opposite with `set -e` it's implicit and if script should continue after a failed command `|| true` can be used.

Comment: indeed from bash manual _wait : Otherwise, the return  status is the exit status of the last process or job waited for._ so when there are multiple process each process must be checked

Comment: however in case of failure it may be safe to wait for all child processes

Comment: for example `trap 'kill $(jobs -p)' EXIT`

Comment: `$?` is the default status of `exit`, so this could just be `wait || exit` with the exact same behavior.

Comment: BTW, I'd suggest either `>&2 echo "..."` or `echo "..." >&2` as better practice -- putting the redirection in the middle of the command is a bashism; `/bin/sh` isn't guaranteed to support it, so demonstrating it encourages nonportable habits.

Comment: fixed, usually i use the redirection at the end don't know where i've seen the infix notation and seemed falsely easier to understand and even more usually as the failing command already prompted the error the echo is useless

Answer (score 1):

I implemented the functionality by hand in a function.

```
# Wait for subprocesses with pids passed as arguments, exit if any failed.
# $1 info_string: to show the command that the failure/success relates to.
# $* list of pids to wait for and check.
wait_and_check () {
    info_string=$1
    shift
    for p in $*; do
        if wait $p; then
            echo "$info_string process $p success"
        else
            echo "$info_string process $p Failure!"
            exit 1
        fi
    done
}
```

Usage:

```
pids=""
for p in $bunch_of_stuff ; do
    stuff_function $p &
    pids+=" $!"
done

wait_and_check "stuff" $pids
```

This feels like many should have had the need for something similar, so I'm surprised there isn't a ready-made solution for that.

One shortcoming is that it's hard to check for the error code of the processes.

Comment: Please consider using a proper bash array instead of a string that contains spaces when you need a list. Initialize with `pids=( )`; append with `pids+=( "$1" )`; expand with `"${pids[@]}"`; and use `"$@"` instead of `$*`. The current code is needlessly fragile -- if for some reason you had `IFS=0` set by a function somewhere else, a pid of `1014` would be split into two entries, `1` and `14` on unquoted expansion; and if you somehow had a value that could parse as a glob slip in, expanding would replace it with a list of matching filenames.

Comment: Insofar as what asked for in the question is `wait` to have `set -e` behavior, using an `if/then/else/fi` block with `echo`s in all the branches also seems contrary to the desired terseness, when `wait || exit` would do.

Comment: ...btw, if you want to wait for *only the next single command to exit* and collect its exit status, in modern bash there's a flag available for that: `wait -n`.

Comment: note that exiting and not killing all subprocess will lead to race conditions because after new run old processes and new may run over same data.

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul Thanks for the heads up, I wait in a trap. Maybe I should kill in case something hangs, but I have to say "good enough" at some point.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy how would you use the || construct to also display an error message? I'm fine with the if-then-else since I hide it in a function, but I'm curious of how it would look like in real bashese.

Comment: @Gauthier, you asked for `set -e`. That *doesn't* display an error message. Though -- `wait -n || { retval=$?; echo "Process failed with status $retval" >&2; exit "$retval"; }`. Or, more typically, I'd have a function like `die() { retval=$1; shift; echo "$*" >&2; exit "$retval"; }`, and `wait -n || die "$?" "Called process failure"`, or such.

Comment: A common idiom for handling specific children while still avoiding races and zombies is to first "wait $pid" in an "until error or last iteration" loop, or more elegantly in Bash "wait -n" (or "wait -fn" depending on desired semantics) in an "until error or none left" loop, and then for all trailing children do a blanket "wait" (or a "wait || :" if you no longer care about errors for the remaining children). See my answer (just added now) for a working example.